# Connecting to XE database

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oraclereports

I am on Oracle Developer suite 10g. I am trying to connect Oracle Reports to Oracle db XE 18c.

Here's is my tnsnames.ora files...

1- XE db

---

## tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

## Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_XE =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Eslam-PC)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =

(DESCRIPTION =

(ADDRESS_LIST =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))

)

(CONNECT_DATA =

(SID = CLRExtProc)

(PRESENTATION = RO)

)

)

2- Dev suite

---

## tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\DevSuiteHome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora

## Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =

(DESCRIPTION =

(ADDRESS_LIST =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Eslam-PC)(PORT = 1521))

)

(CONNECT_DATA =

(SERVICE_NAME = PLSExtProc)

)

### )

When I try to connect, I get the following errors:

```
Unable to connect to the specified database.

TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified.
```

I added the following to the tnsnames.ora file of dev suite...

XEPDB1 =

(DESCRIPTION =

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Eslam-PC)(PORT = 1521))

(CONNECT_DATA =

(SERVER = DEDICATED)

(SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)

)

)
XEPDB1 is my db service name. Eslam-PC is my host.
But when I tried to connect again from Reports builder, I got error

```
"No matching authentication protocol."
```

P.S. I have another 10g database enterprise edition installed. But it's service and listener start manually. And I did not start them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 10g client can't connect to an 18c server; the version difference is too great. You need to upgrade your client to at least 11.2.0.3 (11gR2) or preferably 12c or later. Note that Oracle 19c and 21c are the only currently supported versions. 18c and older are past end-of-life.

Comment: I remember I've read about a workaround.

Comment: 10g clients and 18c servers don't share any encryption algorithms for authentication/passwords. They literally can't communicate.